# How to retrieve data from sqlite in using sqlalchemy?

Tags: sql, sqlite, flask, encryption, sqlalchemy

```
class BlogPost(db.Model):
users = db.relationship(User)

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
Username= db.Column(db.Text)
Password = db.Column(db.LargeBinary(length=500),nullable=True)
Strength=db.Column(db.Text)
```

I have these columns in data base table and when I want to retrieve the data :

```
user = User.query.filter_by(username=current_user.username).first_or_404()
posts=BlogPost.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).all()
```

When I try to access each value in posts for example post[0], the datatype shown is:

```
<class 'password.models.BlogPost'>
```

I am trying to make a password manager and I have encrypted the passwords before storing it into the database and by doing so it changes to base64(bytes) and hence I want it to retrieve it in the datatype in which it was stored,so that I can decrypt it, however when I  Try decrypting it it says that `token must be in bytes` , can someone help me solve this issue.

I have another 'USER' table for storing user data, which is email,password,etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access post[0], you are accessing the entire post object.  Try using post[0].password.